# Scala function takes a map, modify the values and returns a map

Tags: scala, collections, for-comprehension

I am trying to get my head around Scala `for` comprehensions as they relate to `Maps`. I have the following code and my intent is to break out the key-value pair, do something to the value and return the modified `Map`. Am I using the right function or should I use something else?

```
val kvpair = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)

def multiplyValues(map: Map[Char, Int]) = {

          for {
              char <- map._1  
              value <- map._2 * 2
          } yield (char, value )
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Map`, method `mapValues` conveys this requirement; for instance,

```
kvpair.mapValues(_ * 2)
```

doubles each value in the map.

Comment: Note that `mapValues` is lazy, so if you write `val m = kvpair.mapValues(_ * 2)` the values will be recomputed every time you use `m`. This often isn't a big deal if you're aware of it and careful, but it's easy to forget.

Answer (score 3):

As simple as :

```
def multiplyValues(map: Map[Char, Int]) =
  for {
    (char,value) <- map
    modValue = value * 2
  } yield (char, modValue)
```

or

```
def multiplyValues(map: Map[Char, Int]) =
  for ((char,value) <- map) yield (char, value* 2)
```

or even

```
def multiplyValues(map: Map[Char, Int]) = map mapValues (_ * 2)
```

Comment: Very many thanks the first for {} yield () solution has helped me a lot.

Comment: @Faktor10 You should probably also know, this form have far more general use than only in collections. It could be applied also to [`Option`s](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option), [`Either`s](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either), [`Future`s](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) of [different kinds](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html), [test generators](https://www.scalacheck.org/files/scalacheck_2.11-1.12.2-api/index.html#org.scalacheck.Gen)

Comment: @Faktor10 so you should undertand [this concept](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html), and [the more fundamental laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29) behind it

Comment: awesome thank you for these links, I am also slowly working through the classic first edition [Bird and Wadlers Introduction to Functional Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Functional-Programming-International-Computing/dp/0134841891)

Answer (score 1):

As other have stated here, the method you might be looking for is called `mapValues`:

```
val myMap = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
val newMap = myMap.mapValues(_ + 1)  

println(newMap) //Map(one -> 2, two -> 3)
```

But you have to be very careful with that method, since its underlying implementation is a view, meaning it is lazily evaluated.  Since most of the other methods on `immutable.Map` do not behave similarly, this can be surprising, confusing, or lead to bugs.  For example:

```
val it = Iterator.from(0)
val myMap = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
val newMap = myMap.mapValues(_ + it.next)

println(newMap) //Map(one -> 3, two -> 5), as expected
//Try printing again, though:
println(newMap) //Map(one -> 5, two -> 7), I thought this map was immutable!
```

So the values in `newMap` are reevaluated each time the map is iterated!  This is done as an optimization by delaying evaluation of the map and avoiding iteration when possible.  This might be counter-intuitive, and this  method even has [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642/scala-why-mapvalues-produces-a-view-and-is-there-any-stable-alternatives) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982743/scala-map-on-a-map-much-slower-than-mapvalues) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450887/scala-map-mapvalues-stackoverflowerror) and [blog posts](http://blog.bruchez.name/2013/02/mapmap-vs-mapmapvalues.html) dedicated to it because of issues related to this confusion, worth reading if you are interested in using this method.

One way to gain a stable mapping while using the concise `mapValues` syntax is to `force` the underlying `view` implementation of the map:

```
val newMap = myMap.mapValues(_ + it.next).view.force //now stable!
```

You can also call `toSeq` and then `toMap`, but this has performance implications.

At then end of the day, it might be simpler to just use a regular `map` or a `for` comprehension:

```
//If you prefer "map":
myMap.map { case (key, value) => (key, value + 1) }
//If you prefer "for"
for { (key, value) <- map } yield (key, value + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time to explain. I wasn't previously aware of the mapValues function.