# Scala StackOverflowError when getting value from Map

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, scala-collections

After some refactoring we suddenly see this happening at runtime:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.get(MapLike.scala:249)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.get(MapLike.scala:249)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.get(MapLike.scala:249)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.get(MapLike.scala:249)
at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.get(MapLike.scala:249)
```

We found similar issues but none of them had exactly this trace:

- [StackOverflow with map.get](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paris-scala-user-group/ztjlytGVsmg)
- [Scala Map.mapValues stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450887/scala-map-mapvalues-stackoverflowerror)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mentioned issues point to the lazyness of `MapLike.mapValues` and after some further research we found the cause.

We have some cleanup code that is periodically called and does something like this:

```scala
  case class EvictableValue(value: String, evictionTime: Instant)

  val startData = Map(
    "node1" -> Map(
      "test" -> EvictableValue("bar",  Instant.now().plusSeconds(1000))
    )
  )

  // every n seconds we do the below code
  // here simulated by the fold
  val newData = (1 to 20000).foldLeft(startData){(data, _) =>
    data.mapValues { value =>
      value.filter(_._2.evictionTime.isBefore(Instant.now()))
    }
  }

  // this stack overflows
  val result = newData.get("test")
```

the solution was to switch to `Map.transform`

```scala
data.transform { (_, value) =>
    value.filter(_._2.evictionTime.isBefore(Instant.now()))
}
```

or to force the view as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883167/42198)

```scala
data.mapValues{ value =>
    value.filter(_._2.evictionTime.isBefore(Instant.now()))
}.view.force
```